# How to C14N, Whitelist validation user input

Tags: java, security, jsp, validation

I am currently trying to create a safe login that only deals with username and passwords.

I've been reading about ways to prevent injection attacks, and C14N / Whitelist validation seems like a common practice. However, I can't figure out exactly how to canonicalize then validate user input.

My login is in a JSP page, which then processes the input through an httpservlet and checks if the user input matches the one in the database.

I have a few questions :

1. How do I canonicalize? Is there existing tools for me to use or do I have to create my own version?
2. Where do I canonicalize and validate - in the JSP page or Java servlet?
3. Do I need to whitelist validate, or is sanitization good enough for user input (usrname/pw)?
4. Are there tutorials / examples of the actual implementation so I can further understand this?

Theoretically, it all makes sense. But all the web docs that I am viewing don't explain how to do it.

Comment: For canonicalization, it is not applicable here; it doesn't make sense to canonicalize username/password. sanitization can be used (e.g. alphanumeric username). I think you are misunderstanding the concept of canonicalization. For SQL injection, you can prevent it by parametrizing all your SQL statements.

Comment: Both accountname and password are strings. How can I use parametrizing here to prevent SQL injections? I'm not sure if this is correct, but parametrizing only helps indicate what type of data should be inputted. As far as I see it, parametrizing 2 strings does not increase the security.

Comment: you should read the comic about [little bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327).